Integration using complex number
Question
Find values of m for which the below integral is zero.
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x) ....\cos(mx)dx$$
My Approach
By trial, I found $m=1,2,5$ but cannot find any method
I know $2\cos(x)= e^{ix} + e^{-ix}$ but I want to apply it, how to apply it here? I applied King's too but it did not help. Any hints? Also any other methods to solve this question are welcome.
Similar questions:
How to prove that $\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\cos{(2x)}\cos{(3x)}\cos{(4x)}\cdots\cos{(2005x)}dx$ is positive
But all of these use modulo, which I do not know

Isn't this simply $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \cos \left(m(m+1)x \right) dx$?

@Kraken is that the expression you meant? Your integral is zero for all positive integer $m$.

@Kraken how? Pretty sure its not

@user8268 cosx, cos3x are even too

@Someone Your integral is zero if $\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4}$ is not an integer, i.e. iff $m = 4k+1$ or $m = 4k+2$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, for instance, $m = 1$, $m=2$, $m=5$, $m=6$, etc... If you want, I can expand this brief comment into a detailed answer.

Oh right sorry, I directly went from real to complex to real, it should be $\Re \left( \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{\iota m(m+1)x} \right)$ which should be doable via contour integration. @ChrisLewis

Writing, as you suggest, $2\cos(kx) = z^k + z^{-k}$ ($z=e^{ix}$), see whether your product, written as a polynomial in $z^{\pm1}$, contains a term with $z^0$. That's the same as checking whether among the $2^m$ sums $\pm1\pm2\pm\dots\pm m$ at least one is $0$. Looking at the sum mod $2$ certainly helps, but might not be enough.

This was on the 1985 Putnam Competition paper. Q5 if I remember correctly. Look at m (mod 4) to see the pattern.

@RedFive Yes, but you probably meant "The integral is zero whenever $m$ is not congruent to $0$ or $3 \pmod 4$", right? When $m \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, the integral is not zero.

@Bml it has been a while since I looked at the problem properly but from memory it comes down to whether or not the $m$ elements can be split into two sets with equal sum. Otherwise there is a constant term in the integrand when converting to complex exponents.

@Bml Yes, please elaborate on how you got that, and do keep this elementary,

@Someone Yes, I like to do all the steps in an elementary way, so I will do it using various methods, but it will take some time.

This question can be solved quite easily using compound analysis. Try using residue theory. :$z=\exp(ix)$

@Someone - I missed the updated comments while writing an answer. Let me know if any steps aren't clear.

@ChrisLewis thank you, I did not get the 2nd part, as I do not know what modulo means, if it has to be used, I'll learn about it, if possible, do suggest other methods

@Someone it doesn't really use modulo, but it's a useful shorthand (you'll have seen other people using it in the comments). To say "$a \equiv r \pmod n$" (read "$a$ is congruent to $r$ modulo $n$) just means that $a$ leaves a remainder of $r$ when divided by $n$. It's worth reading about if you haven't come across it before.

I read a bit about and and got it, thank you so much!@ChrisLewis

Let
$$P_m(x)=2^m \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x) \cdots \cos(mx)dx$$
So the integral we're interested in is
$$I_m=2^{-m} \int_0^{2\pi} P_m(x) dx$$
Using the suggested complex form,
$$P_m(x) = \left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)\left(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}\right)\cdots \left(e^{mx}+e^{-mx}\right)$$
The terms of the expansion of this product will be of the form $A_{k,m} e^{ikx}$ for $-\frac12 m(m+1)\le k \le \frac12 m(m+1)$.
By symmetry, we note that $A_{k,m}=A_{-k,m}$, so for $k \neq 0$ we have
$$A_{-k,m} e^{-ikx}+A_{k,m} e^{ikx}=2A_{k,m} cos(kx)$$
whose integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ is zero. The only possible term whose integral is non-zero occurs at $k=0$; so the problem reduces to finding which $m$ have $A_{0,m}=0$.
Since all coefficients are non-negative, this is equivalent to the following question: for which $m$ does the equation
$$1\pm2\pm3\pm\cdots\pm m=0$$
have a solution?
For instance, it's easy to verify that no choice of signs makes $1\pm2\pm3\pm4\pm5$ equal to zero, but for $m=4$ we have $1-2-3+4=0$.

To partially answer this new question, we may simply use parity: modulo $2$,
$$1\pm2\pm3\pm\cdots\pm m\equiv 1+2+3+\cdot+m=\frac12 m(m+1)$$
If the $m^\text{th}$ triangular number is odd, this certainly has no solution; and it's easy to prove that this happens exactly when $m\equiv 1$ or $m\equiv 2$ modulo $4$ (ie $m=1,2,5,6,9,10,\ldots$): the integral $I_m$ is zero for these values.
Finally, to show that $I_m$ is non-zero for all other $m$, note that $1+2-3=0$ and $1-2-3+4=0$, so $A_{0,3}>0$ and $A_{0,4}>0$.
If $A_{0,m}>0$ for some $m$, then we can take a sum that gives zero for $m$ terms and add
$$(m+1)-(m+2)-(m+3)+(m+4)=0$$
to give a sum that works for $m+4$; ie $A_{0,m+4}>0$.
So the integral is non-zero for $m=3,4,7,8,11,12,\ldots$.

$$I=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\prod_{k=1}^m \cos(kx)dx=\frac{1}{i2^m}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{m}(1+z^{2k})}{z^{1+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}}dz=\frac{\pi}{2^{m-1}}\text{Res}_{z=0}(f(z))$$
where :$$f(z)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{m}(1+z^{2k})}{z^{1+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}}$$
we have:
$$\text{Res}_{z=0}(f(z))=\frac{1}{\left({\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}\right)!}\lim_{z\to 0} (P_m(z))^{\left({\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}\right)}$$
Where :
$$P_m(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{m}(1+z^{2k})=\sum_{k=1} ^{m(m+1)}\alpha_{k}z^{2k}$$
therfore $I=0$ if only if $p_m(z))^{(m(m+1)/2)}=0$ and $p_m(z))^{(m(m+1)/2)}=0$  if only if $m(m+1)/2$ odd number
Therfore:
$$m(m+1)=2(2k+1)$$
This implique $m=4n+1 $or $m=4n+2$
